# MySQL query for lowest price

Tags: mysql

We got table with different products when it is displayed on webpage I want to display lowest price first but not <> 0 and joint to price = 0 and then
join to maximum price with ASC order. I tried to do it with lots of queries.But is it possible to do in one query?

Comment: I'm confused by the double negative "but not <> 0", please give a clearer explanation

Comment: Perhaps you can show your multiple queries so we get an idea of where you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for get lowest price you can use this,

```
select itemcode, price from item where price>0 order by price asc limit 1
```

Record is for the lowest, for the highest price, change "ASC" to "DESC"

Comment: @DAVE you don't have to shout here. Just have a look at the SELECT statement and change from price>=0 to price>0

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 select top * (price) from table
 where price>=0
 order by price
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it but is display max price first then min and then 0. Client as for lowest price first but not 0 then higher price but not 0 and then price = 0